# Problema na inicialização da aplicação?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, iis, nhibernate, listener

Tenho uma aplicação em asp.net mvc 5 hospedada em um servidor dedicado e em alguns momentos quando o Application Pool está sem uso e o IIS levanta ele no primeiro acesso estou recebendo o seguinte erro:

```
System.ArgumentException: Source array was not long enough. Check srcIndex and length, and the array's lower bounds.
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length, Boolean reliable)
   at System.Array.Copy(Array sourceArray, Int32 sourceIndex, Array destinationArray, Int32 destinationIndex, Int32 length)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.set_Capacity(Int32 value)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.EnsureCapacity(Int32 min)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.InsertRange(Int32 index, IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at System.Collections.Generic.List`1.AddRange(IEnumerable`1 collection)
   at NHibernate.Event.EventListeners.InitializeListeners(Configuration cfg, Object[] list)
   at NHibernate.Event.EventListeners.InitializeListeners(Configuration cfg)
   at NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory()
```

O problema desse erro que ele não ocorre com frequência é uma vez ou outra e está bem difícil descobrir resolve-lo, quando acontece esse erro ao reiniciar o *Application Pool* ele deixa de acontecer.

Comment: Olá Adriano seja bem vindo, é interessante dá uma lidinha no [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender melhor as regras do site.

Comment: Pesquisando no google encontrei esses dois links que achei parecidos com seu problema http://www.sitefinity.com/developer-network/forums/bugs-issues/source-array-was-not-long-enough-check-srcindex-and-length-and-the-array-s-lower-bounds 
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=35179